# Is there a way to do a hot reload in compojure?

Tags: clojure, reload, compojure, foreman

I'm new to clojure and compojure and I was wondering if there's a way to do a hot reload of code changes as you can with Ruby's Sinatra (with the shotgun gem) or Java's Play!

I'm following along with this [Heroku tutorial](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application) so if there's a way to do it with the foreman gem that would work too.

thanks!

Comment: I just answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21411586/2129082). Hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this SOq:

- [Compojure development without web server restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665760/compojure-development-without-web-server-restarts)

and this tutorial:

- http://mmcgrana.github.com/2010/03/clojure-web-development-ring.html

The suggestion is to use ring's [reload middleware](http://mmcgrana.github.com/ring/ring.middleware.reload.html).

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Compojure make it even easier by incorporating all of the middleware into a single function call:

https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Getting-Started

In particular...

```
(require '[compojure.handler as handler])

; define my-routes in here as normal
(handler/site my-routes)
```

I'm using some of this in my own projects.  It works well, but I'll switch back to choosing ring middleware directly if I decide that I need to add or remove anything.