# Clojure live browser reload on Linux

Tags: clojure, livereload

Is there something like [Rack-LiveReload](https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload) that could be used along with a tool like [Guard-LiveReload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) for Clojure development? I really cannot make do without live reloading now that I have used it. If there is nothing more convenient I could download the [LiveReload JS file](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js)  and manually include it in my app and use that with Guard-LiveReload, but I would prefer it if there was an all Clojure solution. I cannot install the LiveReload app on my machine because I am using Linux, so that is why I would need something like Guard-LiveReload.

I am new to Clojure, but so far I am going to go with Ring and Compojure, which perhaps might make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this can be done very easily, but with Grunt and https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch (which has built in LiveReload support), Grunt will work with any language.

Answer (score 1):

I was poking around the c2 library and discovered the author created a liverelaod server in Clojure.

https://github.com/lynaghk/c2/tree/master/vrepl

He also has a screencast on his website.
http://keminglabs.com/c2/

Grunt will probably work for you, but since you asked about a Clojure implementation I thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Imho the best and idiomatic way to go in your case could be to migrate from Ring Jetty adapter to [http-kit](http://http-kit.org) which provides [hot code reload](http://http-kit.org/migration.html#reload) out of the box. It also supports Websockets and it has a noticeable [performance](http://http-kit.org/600k-concurrent-connection-http-kit.html)

Of course it's compatible with Ring & Compojure: *HTTP Kit is a minimalist, efficient, Ring-compatible HTTP client/server for Clojure. It uses a event-driven architecture to support highly concurrent a/synchronous web applications. Feature a unified API for WebSocket and HTTP long polling/streaming*

Comment: Hot code reload isn't really the same as LiveReload - LR triggers a refresh in the browser when web content changed, not when Clojure code changed.