# How to integrate figwheel with ring server to get back-end auto-reload?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, ring

I am new to clojure/clojurescript web development.

1. Use `lein ring server` and the modifications(for example routes) will be automatically reloaded to the server(hot-deploy).
2. Use `lein figwheel`, and it will spy on the changes of cljs source files and updated to the page accordingly.

Now I started `figwheel` and modified the back-end code(for example the routes). After I reload the page, the modified contents was not updated.

So Is there a way to integrate figwheel with the ring server so that the back-end change can be updated automatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ring middleware [wrap-reload](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.reload.html) will do this for you. There is also a very nice leiningen template called [Chestnut](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut) which will set up a project for you with Figwheel and an auto reloading Ring backend.

This question shows an example of wrap-reload usage [Compojure development without web server restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665760/compojure-development-without-web-server-restarts)

Comment: Chestnut works! After check for the source code, I found that chestnut will start a jetty server when calling `(run)`. Simply add the `wrap-reload` middleware will not work(I've tried it before asking). So the reason may be that `lein figwheel` will not start jetty server at all. I'll try to find out later.

Comment: Is there a way to do this only with `lein figwheel` (without chestnut)?

Comment: Sure, copy what they do for the server in Chestnut or use wrap-reload directly.