# Compojure - how to start server from a function?

Tags: web-applications, clojure, compojure, ring

I'm writing a toy application to learn about Compojure, and using it for database-backed web-applications.
I know, I could create a uberjar that automatically launches the server on login, if I compile with `lein ring uberjar`. Now I want to experiment with a multifunctional **.jar** file, the idea is that upon launching the jar I can decide if I want to do database administration or start the server.

In my **core.clj** I have defined some routes via `defroutes` and provided that in the **project.clj** under `:ring {:handler ...}`.

My question now is: how can I just start the ring server from a function, with as few dependencies and code as possible?

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665760/compojure-development-without-web-server-restarts) has examples on starting the server from the `-main` function, but uses a pleothora of dependencies I can't resolve, some occult functions without explanations, and is almost sure to be outdated for two years.

I can't find any hints in the Compojure documentation and wiki, pointers to docs/tuts are welcome, too.

**Edit:** A working version, from schaueho's answer and the ring tutorial:

```
(ns playground.core
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :refer :all]
            [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]))


(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [query]
    (do (println "Server query:" query)
       "<p>Hello from compojure and ring</p>"))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "<h1>404 - Page not found</h1>"))


(run-jetty app-routes {:port 8080 :join? false})
```

For some reason, calling `run-jetty` would give me ClassNotFoundExceptions with the exact same code before I restarted the REPL. I guess a polluted namespace had prevented it from working.

Comment: Yeah, Compojure has nothing to do with that. Ring, however, does. If you can't resolve dependencies it would help to know them.

Comment: Yes, knowing the dependencies from the example is exactly the problem, as they are imported but not listed explicitly; there is a number of clojar-packages with the same names.

Comment: Have you read the answer given in the meantime? Any problem with it?

Comment: Yes, schauenho's answer and link helped me to assure my code had been correct in the beginning; stupid me only had to start a fresh REPL to make it work - I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Getting started](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Getting-Started) section of the ring documentation for an example which uses Jetty (just like `lein ring` does).

You can drop the call to `run-jetty` inside the `-main` function. Compojure routes function as handlers, so you can drop them as an argument to the call to `run-jetty` (as in `(jetty/run-jetty main-routes port)`.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to identify the problem, especially the remark about compojure routes acting as handlers.